# Creating custom button coordinates in tkinter (Python)

Tags: python, tkinter, position

How are we supposed to create multiple buttons in tkinter module(python language), with desired locations(coordinates).
Eg. I want 3 buttons in coordinates (1,2), (3,5), (7,8)

I tried by using this loop-

```py
from tkinter import *
    
Pgame = Tk()
Pgame.geometry('500x500')
    
    
for z in range(109):
    for a in row_list:
        button1=Button(text='hello')
        button1.grid(column=a, row=1)
     
button1.pack 
Pgame.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: Empty rows and empty columns have a size of zero.

Answer (score 0):

@Bryan Oakley is correct, empty rows and columns don't take up any visual space. You can fill empty rows and columns with a `Frame` to keep them from disappearing.

Here's a minimal example that places a button at (1,2) which you can expand to fit all your widgets.

```py
from tkinter import *

Pgame = Tk()
Pgame.geometry('500x500')

button1=Button(text='hello')
button1.grid(column=1, row=2)

frame1 = Frame(Pgame, width=100, height=100, background='green')
frame1.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=2, rowspan=2, sticky='w')

frame2 = Frame(Pgame, width=50, height=50, background='red')
frame2.grid(column=0, row=2, sticky='w')

Pgame.mainloop()
```

[image]

Inspired by an excellent docs site, [TkDocs](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/grid.html).